# Import error google.appengine.api in python flex environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

While importing appengine api in to python flex environment causing import error in local server. 
I have and application running on appengine which is using the flex environment instead of standard.

In my codebase the app directory contains python scripts and yaml file.
When I try to run the py file which through this error.

```
Run command
$ python main.py

from google.appengine.api import app_identity
ImportError: No module named appengine.api
```

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Apache Flex (for AS3 programming).  I couldn't find a tag for python-flex, otherwise I would have added that.

Comment: "flex" is actually AppEngine environment, Basically GoogleAppEngine(GAE) has two environments, 1 **Standard** and 2. **Flex**.

Comment: In that case, I don't think there's a tag for it at all yet :(

Comment: @Brian Yes, There is no tag for that.

Answer (score 4):

The App Engine flexible environment does not provide the API libraries present in the App Engine SDK.

Please check this link [Migrating Services from the Standard Environment to the Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating)